# Chaotigal number existence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

From [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/downloads/printable_post_collections/3003199) source Problem $3$, a number is called *Chaotigal* if it and its successor both have their sum of digits divisible by $2021$. Is such a number even possible?

Now, by successor, I mean we are adding $1$ to the number. When we add $1$ to any number, in decimal form, its sum of digits either increases by $1$, or decreases by a multiple of $9$, and then increases by $1$ according to the number of $9$ s in the tail of the number. So, how can we preserve the divisibility with respect to a standard fixed number like $2021$. Any hints on this? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If the successor's sum of digits decreases by $9k-1$, then divisibility by $2021$ is preserved if and only if $9k-1$ is a multiple of $2021$—which is certainly possible.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes I got it just now, and I think the answer to the problem is $1797$

Comment: A concrete example for such a number is $$\frac{(10^{2021}-1)\cdot 10^{1572}}{9}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a *chaotigal* number exists. To see this, we observe that when we add $1$ to a number, its sum of digits either increases by $1$ (if the last digit is not $9$), or decreases by $9x-1$, where $x$ is the number of $9$s in the tail end of the number.

Now, the first case is clearly not possible, therefore, we must have $9x-1=2021a$ for some $a$. Minimizing, we obtain that $a=7$. Therefore, we can have such an integer which has $1572=\frac{(2021\times7)+1}{9}$ $9$s at the tail, and the sum of remaining digits equalling to $2021$. A minimum such number would be $499\ldots9 (223 \text{times})899\ldots9 (1572 \text{times})$. The number of digits equal $223+2+1572=1797$ digits.